# Blender Material and color Assign

Tags: mesh, materials, modifiers

Hey I'm working on a 3D model in Blender it consists of about 2000 parts, my 3D model is complete now I want to assign materials and add colors to it. But when I assign material into it lags. So is it possible to add colors in 2000 parts in a single blender file? or I should go for any other software?

Comment: 2000 parts are a lot. How many vertices/faces has your scene in total? Are there Subdivision Surface modifiers or other modifiers that generate more geometry? My guess is that your scene has a lot of vertices. This causes the lag. You can check it with the statistic overlay or in the status bar (in Blender 2.9+, right-click on it if the numbers are not shown).